# Node scandir permission denied

Tags: node.js

I am programming a Node js application which will be running on Raspberry PI 3. I am making a functionallity that will scan the `/media/pi` folder and then scan the folders inside that folder to find `config.json`

I have this two functions which do that:

```
function findUSBFolders() {
    return fs.readdirSync(mediaFolder);
}

function findConfigFiles(p) {
    ret = [];
    files = fs.readdirSync(p);
    for(var i in files) {
        if(files[i].startsWith('config')) {
            ret.push(path.join(p, files[i])); 
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

On one raspberry I don't get any errors but on the other I get this:

```
fs.js:912
  return binding.readdir(pathModule._makeLong(path), options.encoding);
                 ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/media/pi/D03E-191B'
    at Object.fs.readdirSync (fs.js:912:18)
    at findConfigFiles (/home/pi/seatcontroller/src/waitConfig.js:78:13)
    at findConfigs (/home/pi/seatcontroller/src/waitConfig.js:61:21)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/pi/seatcontroller/src/waitConfig.js:35:15)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)
```

these are the permissions for `/media/pi`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ ls -l /media/pi
total 4
drwx------ 4 pi pi 4096 Jan  1  1970 D03E-191B
```

I also tried to run `sudo` with `node server.js` but it acts strange, it seems that it gets stuck when I run it with `sudo`.

Let me know if you need some more code.

What could be the problem?

**EDIT**

When I do `sudo node server.js` my chromium browser doesn't get launched. In my code I do this to accomplish that:

```
server.start((err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    server.log('info', `Server running at: ${server.info.uri}`);
    chromium.start();
    main.start(require('./src/apiInvoker'), require('./src/qr'));
    unclutter.start();
});
```

where `chromium` is this module:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

module.exports = {
    start: function() {
        const chromium = spawn('chromium-browser', ['--kiosk', 'http://localhost:3003']);
    }
};
```

It is launched when I run it without `sudo`...

Comment: @CodyG. I don't understand your question

Comment: what operating system are you using on your raspberry pi?

Comment: @CodyG. on Raspbian it's working, but it's not working on some I will provide which one later, because it's not my raspberry